# SSL not working with Visual Composer - Mixed Content issues

Tags: wordpress, ssl, visual-composer, mixed-content

I just activated SSL on a website which also uses Visual Composer. I'm using the Really Simple SSL plugin for that. Everything seems to be set up fine but I still don't have the green padlock but the https is grey.

So I tried to figure out what's wrong and found that there are mixed content problems with some Visual Composer images. It says:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.websitename.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://www.websitename.com/wp-content/visualcomposer-assets/elements/singleImage/singleImage/public/loading.gif'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.
```

The same problem also occurs for close.png, preview.png and next.png of Visual Composer.

How can I fix this? I searched online but couldn't find a solution yet. I use the latest Version of WordPress (4.9.5) and Visual Composer ran an update to 2.4.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the easiest solution to **Mixed Content** errors in WordPress is to use the [Really Simple SSL](https://wordpress.org/plugins/really-simple-ssl/) plugin once you first get your SSL.

Make sure your website URLs in your **General Settings** are updated to include `https://` as well.

If you're still getting these issues, consider the [SSL Insecure Content Fixer](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-insecure-content-fixer/) plugin.

Alternatively, you can also do a "real time find/replace" to replace `http://` with `https://` by adding something like the following to your **functions.php** file:

```
function steffi_live_find_replace( $buffer ){
    if( is_ssl() ) $buffer = str_ireplace('http://', 'https://', $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', function(){
    ob_start();
    ob_start( 'steffi_live_find_replace' );
});
```

I'd recommend the first two plugins before I'd recommend the find and replace method. I'd be willing to wager you just don't have a setting tweaked quite right to secure all URLs and those plugins should help and are about as light-weight as you can get.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I am already using the Really Simple SSL plugin and all other links seem to be fine. The website URLs in General Settings are also set to https. I tried the SSL Insecure Content Fixer but it didn't help, unfortunately. Also not on the "highest" settings. The problem is just caused by the pictures of Visual Composer. I haven't tried the find/replace suggestion yet. Will do this when really nothing else works. I'd rather like to fix this on the plugins side. :/ my Really Simple SSL settings look like this http://prntscr.com/jd44tp

Answer (score 0):

Just want to mention that updating to the latest version of Visual Composer (v17.1.0 as of writing) fixed this for me.